# how to add SSL certificates to Jenkins credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssl, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have two running EC2 machines.

The first instance contains **Jenkins server** that pushes docker images to the other instance that contains a docker registry.
I have created self signed certificates in the second instance (the one that has docker images and docker registry).

**My question here** is how to link the docker certificates with jenkins, so that images go all encrypted from jenkins to the other instance .
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to create url for the local docker registry with https enabled to make it encrypted.Just make your local docker registry secured https url using self signed certificate and push the image to that local registry using secured https url.
you can check this [link](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#get-a-certificate) to know how to configure https for docker local registry.